# Git Repo Copy with commit history in another Account

Tags: github

I need copy entire Github repo from one account to another (It is totally new account with different set Git users)

1. I dont want to migrate from one to another account(I want to have repo in both accounts)
2. Want to retain all commit history on new account.
   Thanks

Comment: Is your question why forking the repository did not work?

Comment: Thanks @mkrieger1, But the 2 accounts are totally isolated no contribution between the two accounts, Also does fork support private Branches?

Comment: I don't know exactly. Or why do you not clone the repository using one account to a local computer and then push it again to the other account?

Comment: But, that way I can't carry old commits, branches, history etc. from old a/c to ne a/c right? I can do one particular branch latest only right. say get latest from old-a/c->'master' to new-a/c->master right

Comment: If you clone a repository you get everything. Have you tried it?

Comment: If I have many branches, how do you push all of them with one command

Comment: That shouldn't be hard to find out with a web search.